# python how to split a list based on a regular expression and sort it

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list that contains file paths like this:

```
my_paths = ['/home/mark/results/chilo/15381_chilo_140618_099_X/15381_chilo.csv','/home/mark/results/chilo/15382_chilo_140610_099_X/15382_chilo.csv','/home/mark/results/chilo/15383_chilo_140616_099_X/15383_chilo.csv','/home/mark/results/chilo/15384_chilo_140620_099_X/15384_chilo.csv']
```

I like to sort the list based on the date in the second level, e.g. 140616 in 15383_chilo_140616_099_X.  So output should be:

```
['/home/mark/results/chilo/15382_chilo_140610_099_X/15382_chilo.csv', '/home/mark/results/chilo/15383_chilo_140616_099_X/15383_chilo.csv', '/home/mark/results/chilo/15381_chilo_140618_099_X/15381_chilo.csv', '/home/mark/results/chilo/15384_chilo_140620_099_X/15384_chilo.csv']
```

What is the best way to do this. I cant make my mind up whether I should first loop through the paths, take the second level like this:

```
for my_path in my_paths:    
    (SeqDir,seqFileName) = os.path.split(my_path)
    (SeqDir_remaining,second_level) = os.path.split(SeqDir)
```

....and then split on underscore, take the date and then sort it and take the path of that date, or use a dictionary and have the dates as keys and the path as values (but then got a problem with sorting).

Appreciate you help.

Thanks!

Comment: when you say sort by the dates, do you want them in chronological order?

Answer (score 3):

split three times on an underscore and get the third element casting to int, the path separators are irrelevant, you just want the number between the second and third underscore:

```
my_paths = ['/home/mark/results/chilo/15381_chilo_140618_099_X/15381_chilo.csv','/home/mark/results/chilo/15382_chilo_140610_099_X/15382_chilo.csv','/home/mark/results/chilo/15383_chilo_140616_099_X/15383_chilo.csv','/home/mark/results/chilo/15384_chilo_140620_099_X/15384_chilo.csv']

my_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split("_", 3)[2])))
```

Output:

```
['/home/mark/results/chilo/15382_chilo_140610_099_X/15382_chilo.csv', 
'/home/mark/results/chilo/15383_chilo_140616_099_X/15383_chilo.csv', 
'/home/mark/results/chilo/15381_chilo_140618_099_X/15381_chilo.csv', 
'/home/mark/results/chilo/15384_chilo_140620_099_X/15384_chilo.csv']
```

If they are actually year/month/day dates, you don't need to use int.

Comment: @JonClements, you might be right, if it is then I suppose we don't even need int

Comment: Yes it will be y/m/d.  I've removed the int. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to extract the thing you want to sort on:

```
def getdate(item):
    ...
```

then

```
my_paths.sort(key=getdate)
```

Your `getdate` function might need to be better than this, but you get the idea:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(my_paths)
['/home/mark/results/chilo/15381_chilo_140618_099_X/15381_chilo.csv',
 '/home/mark/results/chilo/15382_chilo_140610_099_X/15382_chilo.csv',
 '/home/mark/results/chilo/15383_chilo_140616_099_X/15383_chilo.csv',
 '/home/mark/results/chilo/15384_chilo_140620_099_X/15384_chilo.csv']
>>> def getdate(item):
...     start = len('/home/mark/results/chilo/15381_chilo_')
...     end = start + 6
...     return item[start:end]
...
>>> getdate(my_paths[0])
'140618'
>>> my_paths.sort(key=getdate)
>>> pprint.pprint(my_paths)
['/home/mark/results/chilo/15382_chilo_140610_099_X/15382_chilo.csv',
 '/home/mark/results/chilo/15383_chilo_140616_099_X/15383_chilo.csv',
 '/home/mark/results/chilo/15381_chilo_140618_099_X/15381_chilo.csv',
 '/home/mark/results/chilo/15384_chilo_140620_099_X/15384_chilo.csv']
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def sort_links(my_paths, pattern):
# to sort by chilo_xxxxxx
# pattern = r'(chilo_\d+)'
  import re
  my_paths = sorted(my_paths,key=lambda x : re.search(pattern,x).groups(1)[0])
  return my_paths


my_paths = sorted(my_paths,key=f)
return my_paths

    print(sort_links(my_paths,r'(chilo_\d+)'))

['/home/mark/results/chilo/15382_chilo_140610_099_X/15382_chilo.csv', '/home/mark/results/chilo/15383_chilo_140616_099_X/15383_chilo.csv', '/home/mark/results/chilo/15381_chilo_140618_099_X/15381_chilo.csv', '/home/mark/results/chilo/15384_chilo_140620_099_X/15384_chilo.csv']
```